# to insert value into firebase through radio button

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**1. So basically I can retrieved the value from radio button, here is the code**

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName("pointS");
for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++){
    if (radios[i].checked){
        // do whatever you want with the checked radio
        alert(radios[i].value);
        // only one radio can be logically checked, don't check the rest
        break;
    }
}
```

**2. so now I'm trying to send value of radio button to the Firebase, but failed.**

```
    var database = firebase.database();
    var p = database.firebase.ref("points");
    var data = radios;
    database.ref("points").push(data);
```

**3.But if i use this code, the data can easily insert into the firebase. This is only to test connection of the database.**

```
    var database = firebase.database();
    var point = database.ref("current point");
    var data = { 
       point:50
    }
    database.ref("current point").push(data);
```

4. this is the HTML code that I used.

   ```
   <label for="point">Buy point: </label>
   <input type="radio" name="pointS" value="20" > 20
   <input type="radio" name="pointS" value="50" > 50
   <input type="radio" name="pointS" value="100" checked = "checked"> 
   100<br><br>
   ```

   I want to insert info of question number 2 into Firebase. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you sure having this node available `var p = database.firebase.ref("points");` or you can check the same code with `var p = database.ref("points");`

Comment: realy easy example `function writeUserData(userId, name, email, imageUrl) {
  firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
    username: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
  });
}`

Comment: what does your failed example show for an error?

Comment: Okay ,I've already fixed it. But the data still not inserted into Firebase. @Rohit.007

Comment: I'll try that code. @Rohit.007

Comment: The data cannot be insert into the Firebase. Did I answered your question? @zbnrg

Comment: `radios` is a collection of input elements, not the currently selected radio's value.

Comment: I posted the html code for you to see. @JosephWebber. Do I have to change it the other value?

Comment: I already can store data in Firebase, but I'm not using the radio button since I just want any way to store data in the Firebase. I referred at this link http://mariechatfield.com/tutorials/firebase/step4.html

Answer (score 0):

You're finding the selected radio in your `for` loop and logging it, but other than that you're not doing anything with it. Use the opportunity to put its value in an object for submitting like you do in your 3rd example.

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName("pointS");
var database = firebase.database();
var pointsRef = database.ref("points");

for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++){
  if (radios[i].checked){
    // do whatever you want with the checked radio
    var data = {
      point: radios[i].value
    };
    pointsRef.push(data);

    // only one radio can be logically checked, don't check the rest
    break;
  }
}
```

What you're trying to do in your 2nd example is pass in an `HTMLCollection` to firebase, which is like trying to pass in an array of objects.